# Need help removing rigid toilet supply line

Tags: toilet

As the title states, I'm trying to remove my fixed supply line and install a rigid one.

I've removed the bottom nut that connects the line to the valve, but I can't figure out how to remove the top part of the line that connects to the tank.

[image] [image]

[image]

Comment: I presume you're removing the "fixed supply line" and replacing it with a _flexible_ line not a "rigid one"? Typos are fun. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the nut that connects to the toilet inlet. The metal one, not the plastic one.

The rotate the whole pipe slightly clockwise (as seen in these pictures) to release from the fittings (that's why the offset is there)